# Add item to listbox with javascript in asp

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I want to add items in a listbox with javascript or jQuery 
by clicking a button that executes a javascript function. 
This is what I have:

```
function fctAjouter() {

    var lbxListe = document.getElementById('listBox');
    var element1 = document.createElement("option");

    element1.text = "element1";
    element1.value = "element1";
    alert(' coucou1 ');        // COUOU1 S'AFFICHE 

    lbxListe.options.add(element1);
    alert(' coucou2 ');        // COUCOU2 NE S'AFFICHE JAMAIS 

}
```

But this does not work.
Please help me.

Comment: By listbox do you mean the asp.net control `<ASP:ListBox>`?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
lbxListe.add(element1);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6fmbvzqf/

Comment: when the execution was compléte the listbox is empty

Comment: @Kristoffer: That may work if we're talking about a straightforward `select` HTML control, but if we're talking about ASP.NET then the ID of the control will most likely be different on the rendered page will not be the same as declared in the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this is not [asp-classic](/questions/tagged/asp-classic), please re-tag and learn the difference.

Secondly, you have to bear in mind that ASP.NET controls do not carry the same IDs once they have been rendered if they are server-side.  If you want to know the name of the control then you can either: declare your jQuery code server side and map it to your page, or you can look-up the ID of the control given by ASP.NET using the developer tools associated to whichever browser you use, and refer to this using jQuery.